# Why the mesh is broken?

Tags: mesh, rigging, 3d-view, photogrammetry

I imported a photogrammetry for rig it and animate it, but once I have the mesh it seems to be fractured, although is only one mesh. When I animate it folds in those fractures.What can I do? [image]

Comment: I suggest you edit your question title to something like "rigged photogrammetry mesh doesn't properly animate", which will attract more attention from those with specialist talent.

Comment: Your character mesh appears to have a very low poly-count, which may be part of the problem.   Have you looked at https://youtu.be/YX7OSJ26clo for rigging a photogrammetry mesh?   Unfortunately it may be using an ideal mesh that may not help problem-solve your issue.

Comment: You can merge the parts first, with the Merge by Distance tool. Then may be you want to decrease the polycount with the decimate modifier.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#merge-by-distance
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html?highlight=decimate